# How can I make project in java

Tags: java, project

We have to do java project like a management system and we have source code but the question is how to run it and where? anyone knows?

Queries

- IDE
- How to run it?

Comment: Eclipse is a free and open source IDE for Java. You may wanna check IntelliJ and NetBeans

Comment: What specific problem are you running into? Have you actually tried anything yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already have the source code,

1. Open a command prompt window then cd to the directory where you saved the java program.

   For example, JavaProgram.java is in C:/
2. Type `'javac JavaProgram.java'` and enter to compile your code.
3. Now type `'java JavaProgram'` to run your program.
4. You will be able to see the result printed on the window.

Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

> we have source code

You'll need to compile it.

Then you need to execute it. That could involve web containers with WAR or standalone, executable Java JARs, or directly execute a class file. Without seeing your code it's hard to answer that, but you wouldn't use an IDE to actually deploy/run your code outside of individual development.

You'll also need some server to run it on. That's not unique to Java.

Regarding the original question: "Make a project" - you could use Maven Archetypes or Spring and Quarkus have project starter websites, for example...